# How do I check how much memory to allocate?

Tags: c

Code:

```
int messageFunction(char* message) {
   char* sPtr = strstr(message,"Subject:");
   char* cPtr = strstr(message,"Content:");

   // here is the part I'm stuck at
   char* messageSubject = (char*) malloc(...)
   char* messageContent = (char*) malloc(...)
   ...

   }

void main() {
  char* message = "Subject:HelloWorldContent:MessageContent";
  int result = messageFunction(message);
 }
```

I want to allocate memory for the subject "HelloWorld" and for the content "MessageContent" (Need to work dynamically).

Maybe I need to do something like this, for calculation for `messageSubject`?

`strlen(message)` - strlen(substring after cPtr) - `strlen("Subject:")`

And for `messageContent`:

`strlen(message)` - strlen(substring before cPtr) - `strlen("Content:")`

But I'm not sure how to get "substring after cPtr" and "substring before cPtr"?

Comment: What's the point of having `Subject:` and `Content:` if you don't have any delimiters?

Comment: You can still distinguish between them.

Comment: What are the constraints on `message`?  What happens if I call this function with an empty string, for instance?  What if I call it with `Subject:` and `Content:` appearing in the other order, or only one of the two sub-strings `Subject:` or `Content:` appearing?

Comment: Pretty unclear what the final string is supposed to look like.  Just avoid the standard off-by-one bug, forgetting to include one extra element for the zero terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your intent is to malloc for `Hello world` and `MessageContent` in the message:

```
   char* sPtr = strstr(message,"Subject:");
   char* cPtr = strstr(message,"Content:");

   char* messageSubject = (char*) malloc(cPtr - sPtr - strlen("Subject:") + 1);
```

I also assume that `Content:` is last tag and there is end of string after the content. You don't need allocation and copying here (although you may well do that).

```
   char* messageContent = CPtr + strlen("Content:");
```

If you want to malloc for this too:

```
   char* messageContent = (char*) malloc(strlen(CPtr + strlen("Content:")) + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped according to the values in the debugger, but I now I get "heap corruption detected". I'll try to ask in a new question about it.

Comment: Here is the question if anyone can help, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203604/heap-corruption-detected-after-normal-block

Comment: The problem was solved in the link: Needed to add 1.